# LoD: calling components` components - allowed or not?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, composition, law-of-demeter

Is it allowed to call components' components according to the Law of Demeter?

By component I mean an object

- which was "exclusively" injected into the container or was created in
  the container
- which has the same life cycle with it's container

For example, `Brain` is a component of a `Dog`:

```
partial class Dog
{
    private readonly IBrain brain;

    public Dog(IBrain brain)
    {
        this.brain = brain;
    }
}
```

---

Here is some information I found:

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter

> Your method can call methods on its own fields directly **(but not on
>   the fields' fields)**
>
> ---
>
> message target can only be one of the following objects:
>
> ... an object referred to by the object's attribute

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/demeter-method/LawOfDemeter/paper-boy/demeter.pdf

> A method of an object should invoke only the methods of the following
>   kinds of objects:
>
> ...
>
> any objects it creates/instantiates
>
> its direct component objects

---

And here is a case:

```
partial class Dog
{
    public void Command(string cmd)
    {
        var movement = brain.GetMemory().GetMovement(cmd);

        skeleton.ExecuteMovement(movement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is it allowed to call components' components according to the Law of Demeter?

By definition this is not allowed since you should [Only talk to your immediate friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

In other words, the `IBrain` service should not expose its internal services through its interface (assuming that `GetMemory()` returns an `IMemory` service of some kind). Instead, the `IBrain` interface should either provide provide a method that allows retrieving the movement -or-  the `IMemory should be injected directly into`Dog`.

Comment: Think of `IBrain` as a collection of `IMemory` (like `IList<IMemory>`). Do you mean that we can't call any member of object retrieved from collection? It makes a lot of things impossible...